# When scrolling in my UITableView, the hidden Rows are weird when coming back

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

i am experiencing some weird problems with my UITableView.
I have a Grouped TableView with 1 row per section. There is a Textfield in each row.
When i am not forced to scroll, everything is displayed correct.

But if i have to scroll, the previously hidden cells are messed up. they do contain a textfield, but there are many text labels laying over each other.

[Cell http://dcsl.info/b/Untitled.png](http://dcsl.info/b/Untitled.png)
Any advice?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...
if(indexPath.section < [sectionArray count]) {
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10,580, 31)];
    textField.tag = indexPath.section + 22;
    textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    textField.delegate = self;
    textField.text = [item.rechnerValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.section+1];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
}
return cell;
}
```

Comment: Many text labels laying over each other? is this on the same view?

Comment: Post your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: Set unique tag to UITextField and UITableViewCell require to set dynamic CellIdentifier to over come this problem.

Comment: UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10,580, 31)];
    textField.tag = indexPath.section + 22;
    textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    textField.delegate = self;
    textField.text = [item.rechnerValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.section+1];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
[textField release]; use this release line when you added a text filed in the tableview cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10,580, 31)];
        textField.tag = indexPath.section + 22;
        textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
        textField.delegate = self;
        textField.text = [item.rechnerValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.section+1];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];

        [textField release];

    }
    else{
            // Configure the cell...
        if(indexPath.section < [sectionArray count]) {

            UITextField *textFld=(UITextField*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.section + 22];

            if(textFld){

                textFld.text=[item.rechnerValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.section+1];

            }            



        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You have got memory leaks: add `[textField release];`

Comment: Mm. Is it really working? I see problems with `textField.tag`. From where do you know the appropriate tag of `textField`?

Comment: while create the textfield u used textField.tag = indexPath.section + 22; for tag.so we can get it again by the same.

Comment: If we are reusing cell how will we know the tag value?

Comment: Hmm, just copy & pasted it in my code. It works, but the Textfields are getting the wrong values.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are reusing cells. So previously created `textFields` are not removed. When you are scrolling you are adding new and new one on another.

Solutions:

1. Remove previously created `textFields`
2. (better) Just set appropriate `text` to already created text field

Answer (score 1):

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {     
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITextField *textField;
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    if(indexPath.section < [sectionArray count]) {
        textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10,580, 31)];
        textField.tag = indexPath.section + 22;
        textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
        textField.delegate = self;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
        [textField release];
    }
}
else {
       textField = (id)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.section+22];
}

    textField.text = [item.rechnerValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.section+1];

    // Configure the cell...


return cell;
```

}